# Combine more than one image to get a single image

Tags: image, ipad, image-processing, ios5

I've to capture the contents of a `UIView`. There are plenty of methods to capture contents.
The problem is,, if the size of the view becomes too big, the app crashes as it takes huge amount of memory.
So is there any possibility to merge the raw image data (performing **byte-by-byte** operation) in a single file and make image from that??

Answer (score 0):

```
`enter code here`Merging two images to create one single image file

Suppose we have two images with name file1.png and file2.png The code below merges two images.

@implementation LandscapeImage
- (void) createLandscapeImages
{
    CGSize offScreenSize = CGSizeMake(2048, 1380);  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(offScreenSize);
//Fetch First image and draw in rect
    UIImage* imageLeft = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file1.png"];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1380);
    [imageLeft drawInRect:rect];  
    [imageLeft release];

//Fetch second image and draw in rect    
    UIImage* imageRight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file2.jpg"];
    rect.origin.x += 1024;
     [imageRight drawInRect:rect];    
    [imageRight release];

    UIImage* imagez = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();// it will  returns an image based on the contents of the current bitmap-based graphics context.
    if (imageLeft && imageRight)
    {
    //Write code for save imagez in local cache
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
@end
```

Comment: That's the same as of capturing the whole view at once. It brings everything in the memory and for large scale views, the memory becomes to much to be handled.